# Android development communicate a device with a server

Tags: java, android, sockets, amazon-ec2, communication

I have a server that runs on Amazon ec2, which listens to a socket and prints the message ("hello world") sent by the client - which is an activity (android app).

I'm trying to send messages from the activity to the server in a function, for example: after a button is clicked to send the server a message that a button was clicked. I created a connectionHandler class which extends a thread and handle the connection to the server and writes the "hello world" message. I want to create a function called "send" that receive a string, that an activity can call it and the message will be passed to the server.

My connectionHandler is a thread, so when I start it, it just execute the run() function, and once it finished I cannot call other functions to send messages.

I hope I was clear with my question,
Thanks, Itai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a connection to server from android device with a thread call is a very wrong approach.
You should use Asynctask or a library called **volley** which can make your work easier .

Reference link using Asynctask: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Reference link using Volley: http://www.michenux.net/android-volley-and-gson-tutorial-797.html

Comment: But I dont want to do any UI actions in the thread, so there is no sense in using AsyncTask.

I want to send a thread a message from any activity at any time, and the thread will send the message to the server.

Comment: but every time you will send a message to the server a new instance of thread will be created that can lead to memory leak . You have to make thread executor Pool for that or you can use AsyncTask which manges it on its own

Comment: So should I create a class of AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void> for every task I want to write? Like for send a message, connect to a server, receive a response, etc..

Comment: sending a message ,connecting to server and getting response can be made into single task and only single asyncTask class is required to achieve this .